# Visual Studio 2017 Angular handling

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to get into Angular using the VS 2017 MVC Core template.
Everytime I make a change, VS opens the "Script Documents" Folder in the Solution Explorer. Is there a way to prevent this?

Using WebPack, everything works like a charm in Visual Studio Code (adding new files, auto reload etc).

Comment: If you're getting into Angular, I can only advise you to follow their guidelines. And the first of all is to use the Angular CLI to create a new project. I think you should do that, this would be much easier for you in the future !

Comment: thanks, yeah I already did a lot of CLI stuff with VS Code and WebPack ect. :) I now want to check out the standard VS template for Angular .NET Core. But this is rather annoying to handle as of now.

Comment: Well if it's annoying, forget it :P what I mean is, Angular is maintained by a team that also develops the CLI. Why would you use something created by other people, and is opinion based, rather than the official documentation ? It's like saying "I have a Mercedes but when I have an issue with it, I bring it to a Ford workshop"

Comment: Since we use Visual Studio and Micosoft stuff all the way (can't change that). Maybe using VS Code with Angular for frontend development and Visual Studio for backend would the best solution. I get you point though! I totally prefer the normal CLI way. Works like a charm.

Comment: Using Microsoft solutions doesn't mean you have to enforce it everywhere : you can totally use the CLI to create your project, then build it, and deploy it on IIS, while coding on VSCode. But I do get your point, and I can't help you on VS or IIS, sorry :/

Comment: Yeah of course. It's okay ... the thing is, I am working with some stubborn co-workers here ... but yeah, guess I will have to enforce the two IDE approach then :)